# Get note's start and end events from MIDI file with DryWetMidi unity package

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, midi

I'm developing my first rhythm game in unity, and I have track and track's midi. I want to use the drum's midi (or possibly custom midi) as events raiser for note start and note end synchronized with playing audio. So in every moment game should know is player allowed to do each action (for example if bass drum note is playing in midi player can do action1, if snare note is playing - action2 etc.).

I have about 4 different actions totally. And I wanna get start and end events for each of them like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwG2y.png)

Searching around get me to DryWetMidi, that looks like more than enough for my purpose. I'm pretty much new to unity and I didn't managed to figure out how to make it work from DryWetMidi docs, and didn't found any useful tutorials for DryWetMidi as well. So apricate any help with my problem :)

Comment: I'm the author of the DryWetMIDI. But you didn't write what do you want exactly. Just to parse notes from a MIDI file and get their start/end times? In what units? Pay attention to your question and how detailed it is. I have an article for questions like your one: https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/dev/Support.html. Please read it carefully and edit your post to include as many details as possible.

Comment: Sorry for poor describing, let me try once again. I don't want to pars all notes at the beginning, I want to parse them along the playing track, so it synchronized and game would know which note is now playing. So I want midi to "play" synchronized with actual soundtrack, but instead of playing notes just rise certain events. For example when note a1 started I want to get OnNoteStarted event with "a1" argument, or just OnNoteA1Started (I will use only about 4 deferent notes to represent only basic drum pattern). I hope I've described my idea more clear. Let me know if not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you need to start a MIDI file playback, just please visit the page on the library documentation: https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html.

There you'll find an example how to subscribe to "a note's playback started" event. If you drill into documentation using links I've provided there, you'll find the [NotesPlaybackFinished](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/api/Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia.Playback.html#Melanchall_DryWetMidi_Multimedia_Playback_NotesPlaybackFinished) event which will help you to handle "a note's playback finished".

So please use the documentation I've prepared for you. Just start from the article I've provided above and you'll find all the answers there. For specific and non-standard problems, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi/issues/new) on the project's GitHub.